# Is it necessary to merge with upstream/master before merging a Pull Request (even when it's mergable)?

Tags: git, github, git-merge, pull-request

In github, suppose I have a pull request from a fork to `upstream/master`.  Even if the pull request is mergable, is it necessary to merge it with `upstream/master` before merging?

Specifically, suppose at time t1 the pull request was updated with `upstream/master`, but by the time t2 that we want to merge the PR, `upstream/master` has gone a few commits forwards. Let's say the PR is still mergable. Is merging at this time t2 (without updating it with `upstream/master`) going to cause issues for the new changes in `upstream/master`?

Answer (score 0):

It may or may not cause issues. However, as you merge the pull request, you can handle those issues how you normally would in a merge with conflicts.

If the commits don't conflict with her each, then you should be able to merge the changes and be fine

Answer (score 0):

If your pull request is mergeable (there is no conflicts), I don't recommend to do a sync merge before merging it because it complexify the history.

But if you could, I highly recommend to do a rebase just before the merge to have a history easier to read (see post, and especially the first image) : http://www.bitsnbites.eu/?p=221#more-221